# What is the status of IBM Quantum Dynamic Circuits?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

According to this IBM roadmap (https://research.ibm.com/blog/quantum-development-roadmap), the feature of dynamic circuits should be ready by 2022. Now, it is approaching the year end soon, but I still get error messages when running a dynamic circuit.

Do you know if the feature is actually ready by now?

Comment: They mentioned in on "The 12 Days of Qiskit" and made it sound like it was a done deal.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLMVfImNc0o&t=366s

Comment: Can you share your code and the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for dynamic circuits has been announced during 2022 IBM Quantum Summit. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZu5hutqANk) (video) and [here](https://research.ibm.com/blog/quantum-dynamic-circuits) (blog post).

In [IBM Quantum systems](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services/resources?tab=systems) list, systems that support running dynamic circuits have the label "OpenQASM 3":

[image]

Note, however, that you may face some issues if you try to execute your dynamic circuits. You should take these two points into consideration to avoid them:

1. If you follow the old way to load your account, the list of backends that support dynamic circuits will be empty. So, if your run:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
provider = IBMQ.load_account()

backends = provider.backends(dynamic_circuits = True)
backends
```

The result will be

```
[]
```

Instead, use the new `IBMProvider`:

```
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider

provider = IBMProvider()

# Get backends that support dynamic circuits:
backends = provider.backends(dynamic_circuits = True)
backends
```

And the result will be something like

```
[<IBMBackend('ibmq_manila')>,
 <IBMBackend('ibm_nairobi')>,
 <IBMBackend('ibm_oslo')>]
```

2. When you call `backend.run()` method you will have to tell that you are running a dynamic circuit by passing the keyword argument `dynamic = True`:

```
job = backend.run(transpiled_circuit, dynamic = True)
```

Comment: You should do `dynamic=True` instead of `program_id="qasm3-runner"` since the latter is not documented.

Comment: Thank you @jyu00 for the tip. Answer is updated.